# How to use property of a class as template parameter / for specialisation?

Tags: c++, templates

The following example should illustrate my question: If I have a class as a template parameter, how can I use the (constant) properties of the class...

1. Directly, as given by the line marked with (1). As far as I know,
   this should work. Is this the "right" way?
2. As a parameter for template specialisation. So I'd like to specialize one of the Container for fixed, and one for not fixed. Here, I have no idea.

Code example:

```
class IdxTypeA{
  const bool fixed = true;
  const int LEN = 5; // len is fixed on compile time
}

class IdxTypeB{
  const bool fixed = false;
  int len; // len can be set on runtime
}

class IdxTypeC{
  const bool fixed = false;
  int len; // len can be set on runtime
}

template<class IDX> class Container { }

template<>
class Container<here comes the specialisation for fixed len>{
  int values[IDX.LEN]; // **** (1) *****
}

template<>
class Container<here comes the specialisation for not fixed length>{
  ... 
}
```

(The question is not about containers, it's just rough example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to turn the compile-time properties into actual constant expressions by making them `static`:

```
class IdxTypeA {
  static const bool fixed = true;
  static const int LEN = 5; // len is fixed on compile time
}
```

With this in place, you can (partially) specialise on these just fine, with somethig like this:

```
template<class IDX, bool IS_FIXED = IDX::fixed> class Container;

template <class IDX>
class Container<IDX, true>
{
  int values[IDX::LEN];
};

template <class IDX>
class Container<IDX, false>
{
};
```

Comment: I clarified the question a bit: It could be that I also have IdxTypeC, IdxTypeD, and so on which can be fixed or not fixed. All of them should trigger the right specialisation. So I'd like not to specialize for a type, but for a certain property in it.